# share image Xamarin Ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin forms, and in my application has a button to share the problem that is being in my android application I got doing with Intent but in my application ios'm not knowing how to do, someone could help me?

using android

```
public async Task<bool> Share(ImageSource image)
    {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);

        bitmapToShare = await GetBitmap (image);

        if (bitmapToShare != null) {

            CreateDirectoryForPictures("Xpto");

            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine (dir.AbsolutePath, string.Format("xpto_{0}.png",Guid.NewGuid()));
            var stream = new FileStream (filePath, FileMode.Create);
            bitmapToShare.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            stream.Close ();

            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File (filePath);

            shareIntent.SetType ("image/*");
            shareIntent.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile (file));
            shareIntent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
            Forms.Context.StartActivity (Intent.CreateChooser (shareIntent, "Compartilhar"));
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios8/Share/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private static async Task ShareImageAsyc(ImageSource image, string message, string url = null)
    {
        var handler = image.GetHandler();

        if (handler == null) return;

        var uiImage = await handler.LoadImageAsync(image);

        var items = new List<NSObject> { new NSString(message ?? string.Empty) };
        if (!url.IsNullOrEmpty())
            items.Add(new NSString(url));
        items.Add(uiImage);

        var controller = new UIActivityViewController(items.ToArray(), null);

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.GetTopViewController()
            .PresentViewController(controller, true, null);
    }
```

From: https://github.com/jimbobbennett/JimLib.Xamarin/blob/master/JimLib.Xamarin.ios/Sharing/Share.cs